# Python Error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Ru - Помогите мне пожалуйста, всё было хорошо, всё запускалось, я ничего не менял и тут перестало работать.
En - Help me please, everything was fine, everything started up, I didn't change anything and then it stopped working.

Вот сайт с которого нужен парсинг - https://www.avito.ru/rossiya?q=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\123\Desktop\парс авито+\test.py", line 11, in 
maxPages = bs.find("div", class_="js-pages pagination-pagination-*FSNE").find_all("span", class*="pagination-item-JJq_j")[7].get("data-marker").replace("page(", "").replace(")", "")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

product = input("Введите название предмта: ")
delivery = 0

def start():
    print("Фильтры: ")
    d = input("Авито Доставка: ")
    if d == "да" or d == "Да" or d == "ДА":
        delivery = 1
        get_total_pages()

    elif d == "нет" or d == "Нет" or d == "НЕТ":
        get_total_pages()

def get_total_pages():
    page = 0
    url = "https://www.avito.ru/rossiya?cd=1&d=" + str(delivery) + "&f=ASgCAgECAUXGmgwYeyJmcm9tIjo1MDAwLCJ0byI6MTUwMDB9&p=" + str(page) + "&q=" + product
    #url = "https://www.avito.ru/rossiya?q=" + product
    request = requests.get(url.strip())
    bs = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
    maxPages = bs.find("div", class_="js-pages pagination-pagination-_FSNE").find_all("span", class_="pagination-item-JJq_j")[7].get("data-marker").replace("page(", "").replace(")", "")
    print("Всего страниц: " + str(maxPages))
    get_html(page, maxPages)

def get_html(page, maxPages):
    page += 1
    print("1" + str(page))
    url = "https://www.avito.ru/rossiya?cd=1&d=" + str(delivery) + "&f=ASgCAgECAUXGmgwYeyJmcm9tIjo1MDAwLCJ0byI6MTUwMDB9&p=" + str(page) + "&q=" + product
    request = requests.get(url.strip())
    bs = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
    page_pars(bs, page, maxPages)

def page_pars(bs, page, maxPages):
    data = bs.find("div", class_="iva-item-titleStep-_CxvN")
    for value in data:
        try:
            title = data.find("a", class_="title-listRedesign-XHq38").text.strip()
        except:
            title = ""
        try:
            price = bs.find("span", class_="price-text-E1Y7h").text.strip().replace("\xa0", "")
        except:
            price = ""
        try:
            link = "https://www.avito.ru/" + data.find("a", class_="iva-item-title-_qCwt")["href"]
        except:
            link = ""
        info = {'title': title,
                'price': price,
                'link': link
                }
        #print((info["title"], info["price"], info["link"]))
        if page < int(maxPages):
            print("2" + page)
            get_html(page, maxPages)

start()
```

Comment: Значит на том сайте который вы парсите поменялся формат и там больше нет div с указанным классом. Смотрите страницу и меняйте способ поиска требуемых данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Старайтесь по возможности не использовать идентификаторы тагов выглядящие неоднозначно, их генерит код. Кроме того старайтесь использовать User-Agent в заголовках запросов.*
*И еще, не выстравайте цепочки типа*

```py
bs.find("div", class_="js-pages pagination-pagination-_FSNE").find_all("span", class_="pagination-item-JJq_j")
```

*Без проверки результатов работы каждого из элементов*

**Код приведенный ниже**

```py
from requests import Session
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag, PageElement
import re

ua = UserAgent()

s = Session()
s.headers = {
    'User-Agent': ua.firefox
}

base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru'

url = base_url + '/rossiya?p=%s&q=авто'

max_page = 1

def parse_snippet(snip: Tag):
    title = ''
    price = ''
    currency = ''
    link = ''

    if isinstance(title_tag := snip.find('a', {'data-marker': 'item-title'}), Tag):
        title = title_tag.get('title')
        if isinstance(lnk := title_tag.get('href'), str):
            link = base_url + lnk

    if isinstance(price_tag := snip.find('meta', itemprop='price'), PageElement):
        price = price_tag.get('content')

    if isinstance(currency_tag := snip.find('meta', itemprop='priceCurrency'), PageElement):
        currency = currency_tag.get('content')

    return {
        'title': title,
        'price': price,
        'currency': currency,
        'link': link
    }



def process_page(page_number):
    response = s.get(
        url % page_number
    )
    soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    if page_number == 1:
        global max_page
        if paginator := soup.find_all(
                            'span',
                            {'data-marker': re.compile(r'page\(\d+\)')}
                        ):
            
            max_page = max(
                [
                    *filter(
                        str.isnumeric,
                        [
                            item.get_text(strip=True) for item in
                            paginator
                        ]
                    )
                ] or [1],
                key=int
            )

    return [
        *map(parse_snippet, soup.find_all('div', {'data-marker': 'item'}))
    ]



pages = process_page(1) + [elem for item in map(process_page, range(2, max_page + 1)) for elem in item]
```

в `json.dump()` дает такой результат:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Аренда автомобили Любое гражданство в Санкт-Петербурге", 
    "price": "1500", 
    "currency": "RUB", 
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/sankt-peterburg/predlozheniya_uslug/arenda_avtomobili_lyuboe_grazhdanstvo_2318195523"
  }, 
  {
    "title": "Прикурить автомобили в Краснотурьинске", 
    "price": "300", 
    "currency": "RUB", 
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/krasnoturinsk/predlozheniya_uslug/prikurit_avtomobili_2332510555"
  }, 
  {
    "title": "Аренда автомобили с выкупом в Краснодаре", 
    "price": "200000", 
    "currency": "RUB", 
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/krasnodar/predlozheniya_uslug/arenda_avtomobili_s_vykupom_2321517940"
  },
...
  {
    "title": "Toyota RAV4, 2015, с пробегом, цена 1 980 000 руб. - Автомобили в Таганроге", 
    "price": "1980000", 
    "currency": "RUB", 
    "link": "https://www.avito.ru/taganrog/avtomobili/toyota_rav4_2015_2326834752"
  }
]
```

> На текущий момент 840 записей

Comment: Спасибо, но остались вопросы. Как понять: "Старайтесь по возможности не использовать идентификаторы тагов выглядящие неоднозначно"? И я так понимаю, что использовать User-Agent - это значит идентифицировать браузер, что-то вроде того?

Comment: @DanRick к примеру, `class_="pagination-item-JJq_j"` на мой взгляд, выглядит не однозначно. `itemprop='price'` выглядит намного более однозначно, поскольку не имеет не несущего смысловой нагрузки суффикса

Comment: @DanRick, `User-Agent` теоретически идентифицирует браузер. У python requests значение useragent по умолчанию `'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.26.0'`

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!